# My syntax error when i want to make if conditional sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

why this is happen to me? I dont know why my syntax get wrong when i want to make if conditional in my sql

```
IF quantity <= 0
    UPDATE tbl_books 
    SET status = 'Not Available'
ELSE 
    UPDATE tbl_books
    SET quantity = quantity -1
    WHERE isbn = 'tes1'
```

I got an error like this

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF 'quantity' <= 0 UPDATE tbl_books SET status = 'Not Available' ELSE UPDA' at line 1
```

Comment: Is `status` set to `Available` by default?

Comment: yes it is @toonice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, `quantity` is not a variable.  Hence, it is outside the scope of the `if` statement.

You can do this in a single `update` statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_books 
    SET status = (CASE WHEN quantity <= 0 THEN 'Not Available' ELSE status END),
        quantity = (CASE WHEN quantity > 0 THEN quantity - 1 ELSE quantity END)
    WHERE isbn = 'tes1'
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but why my status didn't change? my status still 'Available' while my quantity is already <= 0

Comment: Thank you! it's work now, i just switch the positition the its work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's cause you can't use `IF .. ELSE` procedural construct in a normal SQL query other than in a stored procedure or stored function. You can use a conditional `SET` like

```
UPDATE tbl_books 
SET status = case when quantity <= 0 then 'Not Available' else status end,
quantity = case when quantity > 0 then quantity -1 else quantity end
WHERE isbn = 'tes1';
```

Comment: check your query,two SET statement is present.

Comment: Thank you it works, but why my status didn't change? my status still 'Available' while my quantity is already <= 0